# How do I create a mock server backend API with Postman?

Tags: api, mocking, postman

I'm not understanding this [tutorial](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/mock_servers/mocking_with_examples).

I have a collection set up in Postman, I created a GET request in the collection and an example.

I'm not sure what to put in the request URL for the mock API example and what values to put in key/value in the request call.

Comment: Do you have something like the example in Step 5 on the `mocks` tab of the collection? I’ve sent my GET request to that URL in the past to have it return the mocked data. The route `/something` would then be the same as you would have on a normal request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the examples from the Postman documentation you mentioned - At Step 5 you should have a `mock` for the collection:

[image]

I've saved a simple GET request `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` to the collection using the free [jsonplaceholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) API which will return details about `users`.

[image]

Once you have that response, hit the "Save Response" button and this will save that response as an example that can use with the mock server.

You can make requests against the mock server URL and add your route to the end of this in the Request Field. For me, it would look something like `https://914aae16-28d5-47f1-8954-8a4d7b5e1daf.mock.pstmn.io/users`

[image]